Example of group algebra with canonical involution under certain condition
Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ be a field with involution $\overline\cdot:K \to K$. Suppose the fixed field of $\overline\cdot$ is $K_0$ and $K/K_0$ is a definite extension (and $K_0$ is formally real). Under this situation, each simple component $A_i$ of $KG$ is involution invariant, when the involution is canonical, i.e.
$$(\sum_ga_gg)^*=\sum_g \overline{a_g}g^{-1}=\sum_g \overline{a_{g^{-1}}}g.$$
Computation shows that the canonical trace form on $KG$ is $T(a)=|G|a_{1_G}$. The form $t: KG \times KG \to K$ defined via $$t(a,b):=\frac{1}{|G|}T(ab^*)=\sum_ga_g\overline{b_g}$$
is anisotropic due to the fact that $K/K_0$ is a definite extension.
Can you give me an example of such a group algebra for which one of its simple components $(A_i, {}^*\big|_{A_i})$  is split and $^*\big|_{A_i}$ is a symplectic involution?
Added Later:
Every simple component of group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ is split with unitary involution. Simple components of group algebra $\mathbb{R}G$ have three types:
1- isomorphic to $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with orthogonal involution
2- isomorphic to $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with unitary involution
3- isomorphic to $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{H})$ with symplectic involution.
So we see that these examples do not give a split simple factor with symplectic involution.
